# && and ; chaining commands: does C get executed in A && B ; C if B returns a non-zero exit status?

Tags: bash

```
A && B ; C
```

- A returns an exit status of zero.
- B returns a non-zero exit status.
- C, if performed, returns an exit status of zero.

Then, which of the following two will happen (A is taken for granted to be performed in either case):

1. Bash will perform B and C
2. Bash will perform B but not C

As an extension to this question, how would we modify the chain to allow for the behaviour of the alternative (1 or 2)?

Edit:

I'm not asking about the meaning of && versus ; .

I know A and B gets executed regardless. The remaining scenario is either C are ignored, because B returned non-zero exit status, or B is skipped over and C is re-evaluated on its own merit.

Comment: no, if `set -e` is in effect or your computer is a hit by a meteorite just after running the `B` command.

Comment: @muru I don't think you read my question; I've already seen that other question you linked - it's not a duplicate.  The scope and the question is completely different

Comment: So you do understand the difference between `&&` and `;`?

Comment: @muru Absolutely.  That's not my question.  My question is about the grouping of the logic.

Comment: What grouping? You haven't applied any grouping via braces or parentheses.

Comment: Sorry, but I assume that you have not understood your own question or the basics, because it is executed A, B and C and it is neither 1 nor 2.

Comment: @Cyrus  Not true.  So what I'm sayin is I know A gets executed regardless.  The remaining scenario is either both B and C are ignored, because B returned non-zero exit status, or B is skipped over and C is re-evaluated on its own merit.

Comment: Your Q says nothing about any "grouping". If you're confused about operator precendence, then `&&` has higher precedence than `;`. `A && B; C` is `{ A && B; }; C` not `A && { B; C; }` (all this is simplified, since `;` is not actually an operator, but a separator, and `{ A; }` is not exactly equivalent to `A` in the shell.

Comment: @ptrcao: The exit status of B is irrelevant and C is always executed.

Comment: @mosvy has interpreted my question correctly.  I'm sorry if my wording was unclear but essentially mosvy's reading is correct.  Welcome to leave as answer and I will accept

Comment: @jsotola  You are right; I have fixed the question so that doesn't distract from the main question I was asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> A && B ; C
> ```
>
> A returns an exit status of zero.

In this scenario `B` will be run next, and regardless of the exit values of `A` and `B`, `C` will run.

That sequence groups like `(A && B) ; C`, not as `A && (B ; C)`. You could add a grouping with braces or parenthesis (subshell) if you want to.

> The remaining scenario is either both B and C are ignored, because B returned non-zero exit status,

This doesn't make much sense: B can't get ignored based on the exit status of B itself.

> or B is skipped over and C is re-evaluated on its own merit.

B gets skipped if and only if A returns a falsy (nonzero) status, not if it returns a truthy (zero) status.

Note that the shell has an inverted idea of the truth values of numbers compared to e.g. the C language where zero is false.

If A returns a falsy (nonzero) status, then B doesn't run, but C still does.